# UI Boostrap min-date and max-dates not working in ui-bootstrap 1.3.3

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

This question has been posted a couple of times before, but the issues seems to be specific to different releases of ui-bootstrap-tpls.js. As mentioned in the title, I am using version 1.3.3, and I simple can't get min-date and max-dates to work. My code can be seen in the following; https://plnkr.co/edit/Qr7PREKnNc4b8tfxSNzT?p=preview.

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" min-date="minDate" max-date="maxDate" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats"
          />
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
  </span>
</div>
```

In my controller, I have the following bits of code;

```
//set min and max dates
  $scope.minDate = function() {
    $scope.minDate = new Date();
  };
  $scope.minDate ();

  $scope.maxDate = function() {
    $scope.maxDate = new Date();
  };
  $scope.maxDate ();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have forked your plnkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/OEBAS07JS8rDwXBNeoNE?p=preview

```
$scope.dateOptions.minDate = new Date();
```

This plnkr shows the fixed thing.

You basically need to set the $scope.dateOptions.minDate to new Date. I have commented your toggle function as your inlineOptions.minDate for never set to null, so it never got initialized to the new Date()

You can do the same for max date.